# OGRE app does not run properly

Tags: qt, ogre

I am creating an application using Qt and OGRE. I have followed this tutorial: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/QtOgre.

I get the following output window on running the application:

[image]

The image shows a clipped portion of the background window.

The following code gives an error during runtime:

```
void THIS::paintGL()
{
// Be sure to call "OgreWidget->repaint();" to call paintGL
swapBuffers();
assert( mOgreWindow );
mOgreRoot->renderOneFrame();
}
```

The error is:

```
QOpenGLContext::swapBuffers() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just declared the parameter `winHandle` and did not define different parameters associated to it.

```
winHandle = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(QX11Info::display()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned int)(QX11Info::appScreen()));
winHandle += ":";
winHandle += Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(winId()));
```

Adding the above code snippet after the declaration `Ogre::String winHandle;` and associating it to  params while defining the creation of Render Window worked for me. :)